# git log - how to get an xml output

Tags: xml, git, awk

I need to get all changes in a branch to be further processed by an application that implements a special deployment logic.
At the very least I'd need to get :

- commit sha1
- Commit date
- List of changed files and change type for each

since it's probably trivial to additionally obtain:

- Commit author
- commit notes

would like to grab those as well. Output needs to be XML.

I know there are perl scripts out there that will create a JSON output, but I'd like to stick to XML.

I've tried pretty-format options but can't find a placeholder for the changes, and running
`git log -10 --name-status --pretty=format:"<entry><author>%an</author><commit_date>%cd</commit_date><message_body>%N</message_body></entry>" -- databases/`
just dumps changes between entries...

I wrote an awk script that parses the output, but would like to find something more "native". is there something out there? Perhaps an option that I'm missing?

for anyone so interested, here is an awk script that does what I want. Not sure yet why it needs to be run in gawk on a mac but runs in awk fine in cygwin.

```
# script to parse the output of git log --name-status
BEGIN{ 
    RS="commit ";
    FS="\n";
    print "<log>";
}

NR>1{
    StartComment=0;
    CommentText = "";
    CommitText = "";
    AuthorText = "";
    DateText = "";
    ChangesText = "";
    isLast = 0;

for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
{

if (i==1) {CommitText = $i;}
    if (match($i,/^Author/)) {
    #remove "author :"
    split($i,author1,": ");
    split(author1[2],author2," <")
    AuthorText = author2[1];}
    else if (match($i,/^Date/)) {StartComment=1; ln=i;
    #remove "date :" 
    split($i,dt,": ");
    DateText = dt[2];
    #trim whitespaces
    gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",DateText);
       }
    else if (match($i,/^[A-Z]\s/)) {StartComment=0;
    if(match($i,/\.sql$/)){
        j = i+1
        ch_path = substr($i,2)
        gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",ch_path);
        unitChange = "\t\t\t<change>\n\t\t\t\t<ChangeType>"substr($i,1,1)"</ChangeType>\n\t\t\t\t<Path>"ch_path"</Path>\n\t\t\t</change>";
        ChangesText = ChangesText""unitChange;
        if (!match($(j),/^$/)){ChangesText = ChangesText"\n"}
    }
    }
    else if (StartComment==1 && i>ln) {  {CommentText=CommentText$i"\n"}    }

}

print "\t<entry>";
print "\t\t<commit-sha1>"CommitText"</commit-sha1>";
print "\t\t<Author>"AuthorText"</Author>";
print "\t\t<CommitDate>"DateText"</CommitDate>";
print "\t\t<Changes>";
print ChangesText;
print "\t\t</Changes>";
print "\t</entry>";    
}
END {
    print "</log>"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`git log` will not generate well-formed XML, and message bodies (`%s`, `%b`, `%B`) and notes (%N) are free-form text and therefore may contain invalid XML characters such as control-L, angle brackets, or even the byte-sequence `<![CDATA[`.  (This last will really mess with you if your XML encoder does not handle it for you.  I speak from the experience of trying to interface to a different VCS on which someone had pasted a fake-XML encoder Perl script that failed to encode message log bodies.  The fake encoder did replace angle brackets and ampersands with `&lt;` and the like, but did not handle control-characters—and many messages had ^Ls—nor CDATA, which occurred in one message regarding, naturally enough, a bug when dealing with XML.)

This means that you should write your own encoder.  You *could* do this in awk (I see you included an awk tag) although I probably would not myself.  I would recommend encoding arbitrary text, such as message bodies and notes, using base64 or similar schemes.

(Note that while it is at least rare, Git message bodies can even include ASCII NULs.)

Comment: thanks, ignoring the encoding issues for a second, is there a way to get the commit info as XML including changes from any native git command?

Comment: No, not without modifying the Git source code anyway. If you're willing to discount the possibility of NULs, you can use %x00 between items in `--pretty=format:` formats, and use that to distinguish between (e.g.) the note if any from %N and the log message with one `git log` command. To be 100% sure though, you would have to use `git log --no-walk <commit-id> --pretty=format:%N` to get just the note by itself, for instance.

Comment: Given that many items *are* restricted (there will be no newlines or NULs in author and committer names and dates for instance), you can get everything in just a few separate `git log`s. However, for raw access to contents, you might want to look into `git cat-file --batch-check`, perhaps with a format directive as well. You can get the size followed by raw bytes, so that you know how many bytes to interpret as content.